# Angular - для MPA -

Tags: javascript, mvc, angular2, spa

Хочу использовать Angular для проекта.
Однако это не SPA, а MPA
Т.е. мне нужна возможность запускать различные компоненты на разных страницах.
Допустим в /profile я хочу запускать компонент (и загружать нужные js файлы) только когда эта страница открывается.

А есть еще /catalog - где я хочу использовать серверный рендер для СЕО, а сбоку показывать фильтры где можно использовать возможности Angular

Как такое правильно организовать?

Comment: зачем такой велосипед? используйте Angular с серверным рендерингом

Comment: есть пример с открытом кодом?

Comment: вам лень гуглить? в интернете куча документации по angular universal